# Where do audio files received via whatsapp are saved?

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-520

I cannot locate the file on sd.card or phone memory but it plays just fine in whatsapp. i want to set a particular file as ringtone but cannot do so until I can localise it. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find audio files downloaded in whatsapp by checking the whatsapp folder in Pictures Directory of preferred location either in phone or sd card as you opted in storage sense.

I'm using Lumia 525 using Files app to locate those audio files. You can download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl)